# Postgres partitioned table query scans all partitions instead of one

Tags: postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices
(shop_id            integer not null,
good_id             varchar(24) not null,
eff_date            timestamp with time zone not null,
price_wholesale     numeric(20,2) not null default 0 constraint chk_price_ws check (price_wholesale >= 0), 
price_retail        numeric(20,2) not null default 0 constraint chk_price_rtl check (price_retail >= 0),
constraint pk_prices primary key (shop_id, good_id, eff_date)
 )partition by list (shop_id);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices_1 partition of prices for values in (1);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices_3 partition of prices for values in (2);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices_4 partition of prices for values in (3);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices_4 partition of prices for values in (4);
...
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices_6 partition of prices for values in (100);
```

I'd like to delete outdated prices. The table is huge , so I try to delete small portions of records.
If I use loop and the variable v_shop_id then after 6 times Postgres starts scanning all partitions. I simplified the code, the real code has inner loop by shop_id.
If I use loop without the variable (I explicitly specify the value) Postgres doesn't scan all partitions

here code with the variable

```
do $$
declare
v_shop_id integer;
v_date_time    timestamp with time zone := now();
begin   
v_shop_id := 8;  
for step in 1..10 loop
 delete from prices p
 using (select pd.good_id, max(pd.eff_date) as mxef_dt
             from prices pd
            where pd.eff_date < v_date_time - interval '30 days'
              and pd.shop_id = v_shop_id
            group by ppd.good_id
          having count(1)>1
          limit 40000) pfd
  where p.eff_date <= pfd.mxef_dt
  and p.shop_id = v_shop_id
  and p.good_id = pfd.good_id;
end loop;
end;$$LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

How can I force Postrges to scan one desired partition only?

Comment: Add a condition like `AND shop_id = 42` to the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
I have condition shop_id = v_shop_id in inner and outer query

Comment: Yes, but that won't do. You asked how you can force partition pruning, and I told you.

Comment: yep, It works I know, I'd like to use variables. I don't want to use dynamic query or plenty of similar queries where shop_id is different.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Works for me.  What version are you using?  What is the plan you get?  How do you know it is scanning all partitions?

Comment: I noticed that using the variable in a loop leads to scan all partitions , in my case at step 6 or 7 Postgres starts scanning all partitions (for first steps only one partition is used), but the variable is the same.  If I explicitly specify the value , like you mentioned shop_id=42, Postgres uses one partition only for all steps.